# Netlogo conditional statement with random variable and extra stochasticity

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to add some additional stochasticity to an event occurring.

Employer breeds have their own probability of taking an action. r is a global random-float variable.

The following, whether in a turtle or observer context, does not provide the expected results:

```
ask employers [if (prob-action * 0.5 ) > r [set action True]..]
```

However, what I think is an inferior alternative works:

```
ask employers [if (prob-action >= 0.90 [set action True]..]
```

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: The last statement should actually have an extra parenthesis :

Comment: What's your question here? What is the expected result? Why do say the alternative is inferior? Also, note that you can edit your question.